# Is cache busting by modifying the resource names still the way to go?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser

I have been using cache busting in one form or another for a long time and it always worked as expected, but recently this method does no longer seem to work reliably. There are cases when the browser "seems" to ignore the new version parameter and simply uses the cached version loaded with an older version parameter.

I typically append a parameter _=version with the version to my static resources. The url `https://example.com/resource.js?_=2.0` for example would indicate that the `resource.js` file is for version 2.0.

Is this still the way to go to force the browser to reload resources or should I use any alternative method?

Comment: Please expand on "*recently this method does no longer seem to work reliably*".

Comment: I've added the following: There are cases when the browser "seems" to ignore the new version parameter and simply uses the cached version loaded with an older version parameter.

Comment: Can you provide more details for those cases where it *seems* to ignore the parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It mostly happens in evergreen browsers and if it happens also a hard reload does not seem to solve the problem. I'm also not sure, if the problem is related to the browser or the server but we have been using the same Apache Server Configuration for a long time letting me assume that it is a browser issue. I'm mostly interested, if this method is still recommended or if there are alternatives?